# How to check if database already exists

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I am writing a small Python program that loads some documents into couchdb. 
It would be very convenient to check whether a database with a certain name already exists, so I can either create a new one or open the existing one. What I want to do is something like this:

```
import couchdb

def connect(url, dbName):
    server = couchdb.Server(url)
    if dbName exists: # how do I do this?
        return server[dbName]
    else:
        return server.create(dbName)
```

I know a try-except block would do the trick, but isn't there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way I can think is:

```
import couchdb
server = couchdb.Server("http://localhost:5984")
"dataBaseName" in server
```

Return `True` if a database with the name exists, `False` otherwise

https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python/blob/master/couchdb/client.py#L90-L101

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's indeed a lot nicer.

Comment: There's a good examples of simple commands for couchdb using python in this link: https://gist.github.com/marians/8e41fc817f04de7c4a70.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
try:
    couch = couchdb.Server() # assuming localhost
    db = couch['existent']
except:
    db = couch.create('somedb')
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Seems like there is no better solution to it.