# How to check if a database exists with CouchDB Nano

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano

I need to check if a given database exists before querying it. I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465360/python-couchdb-how-to-check-if-database-already-exists), but I cannot replicate on Node.js using CouchDB Nano.

Does anyone know how to check it using the Nano library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find out there is an API to list al the databases from a given CouchDB server: https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#nanodblistcallback

My bad.

Comment: You can also use [nano.db.info](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#nanodbinfocallback) and check for the "not found" error if you're looking for a specific database by name.